# How to get additional column with row count using two different tables?

Tags: sql, database, mariadb

In my database I have usergroup, usergroup_user tables. I want to make a SQL query which can result something like result(group_id, name, date, users_count).

usergroup table

```
------------------
| group_id| name | 
------------------
|  10     |test1 |
|  11     |test2 |
|  12     |test3 | 
------------------
```

usergroup_user table

```
---------------------
|group_id | user_id | 
---------------------
|  10     |  100    |
|  10     |  200    |
|  10     |  250    | 
|  11     |  250    | 
|  11     |  700    | 
---------------------
```

I want to get this kind of a reusult

```
------------------------------
|group_id | name |users_count| 
------------------------------
|  10     |test1 |  3        | 
|  11     |test2 |  2        |  
|  12     |test3 |  0        | 
------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply do this with the group by, as per the following bellow.

```
SELECT U.group_id ,U.RoleName,COUNT(R.Id)USERCOUNT 
FROM usergroup U
LEFT OUTER JOIN usergroup_user R ON R.group_id =U.group_id 
GROUP BY  U.group_id ,U.RoleName
```

Comment: You must outer join the table `usergroup_user` to get the zero count for group_id 12.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, thanks & yeah I missed that point.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
group_id,
name,
(select count(user_id) from [dbo].[usergroup_user]  where usergroup_user.group_id=[usergroup].group_id ) AS users_count 
from [dbo].[usergroup]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT usergroup.group_id ,usergroup.name,COUNT(usergroup_user.id) as users_count 
FROM usergroup 
LEFT OUTER JOIN usergroup_user  ON usergroup.group_id =usergroup_user.group_id 
GROUP BY  usergroup.group_id ,usergroup.name
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).